# Creating GridView with Picasso images in Android

Tags: java, android, picasa

I'm trying to create gridview with images using Picasso library. I'm creating fragment with gridview and set adapter to gridview, but can not see anything on display.
Here is my adapter code:

```
public class GridViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
    private Context context;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    private String[] imageUrls;

    public GridViewAdapter(Context context, String[] imageUrls) {
        super(context, R.layout.grid_item, imageUrls);

        this.context = context;
        this.imageUrls = imageUrls;

        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (null == convertView) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_item, parent, false);
        }

        Picasso
                .with(context)
                .load(imageUrls[position])
                .fit() // will explain later
                .into((ImageView) convertView);

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Here is the code of my fragment

```
public class ViewMoviesFragment extends Fragment {

    GridViewAdapter adapter;
    public ViewMoviesFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          String[] eatFoodyImages = {
                "http://i.imgur.com/rFLNqWI.jpg",
                "http://i.imgur.com/C9pBVt7.jpg",
                "http://i.imgur.com/rT5vXE1.jpg",
                "http://i.imgur.com/aIy5R2k.jpg",
                "http://i.imgur.com/MoJs9pT.jpg",
                "http://i.imgur.com/S963yEM.jpg",
                "http://i.imgur.com/rLR2cyc.jpg",
                "http://i.imgur.com/SEPdUIx.jpg",
                "http://i.imgur.com/aC9OjaM.jpg",
                "http://i.imgur.com/76Jfv9b.jpg",
                "http://i.imgur.com/fUX7EIB.jpg",
                "http://i.imgur.com/syELajx.jpg",
                "http://i.imgur.com/COzBnru.jpg",
                "http://i.imgur.com/Z3QjilA.jpg",
        };
        View v= inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_fragment, container, false);
        GridView gridview = (GridView) v.findViewById(R.id.poster_view);
        gridview.setAdapter(new GridViewAdapter(getActivity(), eatFoodyImages));



        return v;
    }
}
```

My activity code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        Fragment fragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);

        if (fragment == null) {
            fragment = new ViewMoviesFragment();
            fm.beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment)
                    .commit();
        }
    }
}
```

main_activity.xml

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</FrameLayout>
```

grid_item.xml

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</FrameLayout>
```

grid_fragment.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:id="@+id/poster_view"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:numColumns="2">
    </GridView>

</FrameLayout>
```

When I run my app I get just white window. AndroidManifest.xml have internet permission access. Can anyone help me to show images in gridview?

Comment: @g2o Are you sure OP is talking about `picasso` instead of googles `picasa` ?

Comment: @LJ  in the code is Picasso.with(context), so i asume that is Picasso library

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your GridViewAdapter

```
    Picasso
            .with(context)
            .load(imageUrls[position])
            .fit() // will explain later
            .into((ImageView) convertView);
```

`convertView` is a Framelayout

Comment: I have deleted fit() and now it works, but still now I can't get how resize my images without fit